# How to use custom sound in notifitcation ionic 3 one signal?

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

I'm using Onesignal to push notification in my app ionic, but the custom sound does not ring.

Here my app.component:

```
setupNotification() {
this.oneSignal.startInit('xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');
this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);
this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(data => {
  data.payload.sound = 'coins.mp3'
});
this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
  // do something when a notification is opened
});
this.oneSignal.endInit();
```

}

here my config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="res/raw/coins.mp3" target="res/raw/coins.mp3" />
</platform>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just managed to get this working on my Ionic3 app with OneSignal, and testing on Android 8.0. So maybe this can help someone.
I also updated to Cordova 9, and updated onesignal-cordova-plugin to 2.4.7

I also assume here you already have notifications working, its just the custom sound file that's not working.

My sound file is `alert.wav`, and placed it under 'src/assets/audio` (I created the audio folder)

In `config.xml`, I had to add the following to copy this file to the correct location:

`<resource-file src="www/assets/audio/alert.wav" target="app/src/main/res/raw/alert.wav" />`

(the audio dir will get copied to the `www` dir on build)

Android 8 requires you to create a notification channel/category. You can create a Group and Category in OneSignal settings.
In the Category settings - Sound section, set to 'Custom' and add the name of the file (without the file extension) - in my case `alert`. Everything else can be left as default.

I also found that if you edit it, it seems to be ignored. so I had to create a new Category when testing a different sound file. I recommend for testing, delete the Category and create a new one to be sure - don't bother editing it. Once a notification is sent using this Channel, the channel is created on the users device and cant be removed/edited - user has to uninstall/reinstall the app.

I triggered the notifications through my backend server, this is PHP:

```
        $request = json_encode([
            'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'headings' => [
                'en' => $title,
            ],
            'contents' => [
                'en' => $message,
            ],
            'include_player_ids' => $playerIds,
            'android_channel_id' => 'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee',
//            'android_sound' => 'alert',
        ]);
```

Make sure to copy the new Channel ID from OneSignal into this request payload.

Ultimately didn't need the 'android_sound' value, as it triggers the channel default settings (which has the audio file name), and changing the android_sound value has no effect.

unfortunately you need to create one Category per sound file you want to play which may not suit some use cases - the user will see these channels in their app notification settings.

Some other things I recommend when testing this is to uninstall the App before each build to test specific changes, and running `cordova clean` I found helps too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great Answer. Just added this <resource-file src="www/assets/audio/alert.wav" target="app/src/main/res/raw/alert.wav" />  in config.xml and android_channel_id and android_sound in backend message config. No need to add android_channel_id  in frontend and its worked

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
<resource-file src="www/assets/audio/alert.wav"target="app/src/main/res/raw/alert.wav" />
```

to move the sound file to location that use by onesignal plugin
add this to send code :

```
'android_sound' => 'alert'
```

it worked